# Accumulo Table Name Mapping Issue

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, accumulo

My Accumulo instance was corrupted.  When I started up my instance it threw an error stating that my metadata table was corrupt.  I then backed up my data from the Accumulo directory in hdfs and did an init on my instance.  What I failed to realize is that the Accumulo table names are not listed in the data that I backed up.  The table names are ints.  Is there any place that has a conversion between the ints and the table names?  Or did I screw myself over by doing the init and blowing away Zookeeper?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you blew away ZooKeeper, then yes, you're out of luck, sadly. Same goes for the table configuration which is also stored in ZooKeeper.

If you can piece together the table names from the HDFS files (try `accumulo rfile-info <path_in_hdfs>` to inspect the rfiles), you can always try to import the RFiles to your new instance. http://accumulo.apache.org/1.6/accumulo_user_manual.html#zookeeper_failure may also help.

Feel free to hit up the community mailing list (dev@accumulo.apache.org or user@accumulo.apache.org) and we can try to help you out more.

Comment: I was able to find what I needed in Zookeeper.  Thank goodness that I did not blow it away.

Comment: Great. Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

Init doesn't blow away zookeeper. You may still have a backup under the old zookeeper instance directory, if you're willing to do some manual work to recover.